# Securing Azure Mobile Service

Tags: c#, security, azure

I'm trying to implement global highscores with my game using MS Azure Mobile Service.

It's the firs time I want to use Azure for, well, anything. The problem is I don't know how to secure this method, so nobody can "manually" add something to my db.

I don't want anybody to login (FB, Google etc), I just want my app to send scores and that's it. So that user don't have to do anything.

Could you tell me how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how secure you want your application to be. For starters you could encrypt a secret and send with each request, that would stop people from calling your api without knowing the secret.

Comment: OK but how can I do this - as I said I'm new to this topic. Can you point at some tutorial to look at or give me some code I could use?

Comment: Here is a link to a few different approaches http://naildrivin5.com/blog/2008/04/21/rest-security-signing-requests-with-secret-key-but-does-it-work.html